# images disappeared after saving a big WORD file

Tags: microsoft-word

I had a big word 500 pages word docx file around 130MB. There are a lot of images which I just pasted from SnapIT tool. After I saved the file today, all the images disappear. The images are shown with title of "The image part with relationship ID rld1000 was not found in the file". I did change the name to zip and look for document.xml.rels. The rld's target is all NULL. I don't know where are the media files?

The size of file was 130MB. now it is only 400KB. what the heck with it? I am very desperate to get them back. Does anyone have a solution? Is it possible to get it back? How come 130MB file becomes 400KB just after saving? Thank you so much, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have version history enabled?

If you've turned it on, you can find the previously saved version in OneDrive.

File - info - version history

[image]

If you don't turn on this feature.....it's hard to get your previous files back.

Comment: Thanks Binggo, no I don't have version enable. I changed the extension to zip and unzip it, there is media subfolder, under the media folde, there are only two images left. That is why the file size was reduced from 200MB to 400KB after saving. I am wondering where is these lost images? How come they wre all lost after saving?

Comment: It's hard to find a real reason, the files are lost because they are not saved properly.

Comment: Would enabling File History in Windows have a similar effect on recoverability?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems and they seem to be worse the larger the file gets.    I've had luck saving the file as a .doc instead of a .docx and the problems seem to evaporate. Though, I'm not sure how to get your pictures back.

Comment: Thanks Fezagig, Yes I did save it as doc and it is not successful. I think the file size says everything. when it was reduced from 200M to 400KB, it tells me pictures were all gone. Now the question is why they were gone, gone to where? I just saved the file and they were gone. It kind of evaporates.

Answer (score 0):

I also permanently lost my images (and nothing left in the media directory) and in my case the problem is reproducible and occurs in the following scenario:

1. opening a document on an external disk D:
2. Disconnecting disk D: (because I temporarily changed my activity)
3. Attempt to save the document and cancel when Word offers me to save the file in another location
4. reconnect external drive to D:
5. Save file to D:

When the document is reopened, the images have disappeared.
I reproduced the bug, recreating a word document with only an image inside and running the previous scenario and bingo the image disappeared.

It would be nice if Microsoft fixes this bug, which is very damaging.
And I have trouble hearing the answer "do not copy images directly into Word but rather use Word's insert image function".  If Microsoft propose a feature, it must work!